# Sending mail with SMTP not working in deffrent server

Tags: java

I present our problem:

Technical data: Java, JSF

Functionality: sending mail with SMTP protocol,

For outbound SMTP server smtp.gmail.com google all works perfectly:

```
public void envoisPassword(String mail, String password){

        try {
            /**
             *initlisaser les variable 
             **/
            Properties props = null;
            SMTPTransport transport = null;
            MimeMessage mimeMsg = null;

            /**
             * en va utliser le serveur stmp de gmail
             * **/
            props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail." + "smtp" + ".host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail." + "smtp" + ".port", "587");
            props.put("mail." + "smtp" + ".auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            transport = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", Integer.parseInt("587"), "adresse@gmail.com", "motdepass");

            mimeMsg = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMsg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mail));
            mimeMsg.setSender(InternetAddress.parse("adresse@gmail.com")[0]);       
            mimeMsg.setSubject("msg test ");
            mimeMsg.setText("voici votre mot de passe : "+password);

            transport.sendMessage(mimeMsg, mimeMsg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getCause());
            }
        }
```

By cons when we trying SMTP outgoing server of our domain host.

The execution stops on the connecting line to the server:

```
transport.connect("hp181.hostpapa.com", Integer.parseInt("587"), *****@****.net","password");
```

the server does not reponds

thank you for your efforts